# http://localhost/ is not available

Tags: php, html, ios, netbeans, xampp

I have downloaded **xampp-win32-5.6.11-0-VC11-installer**

I have **Windows 8.1 Single Language** (Also sure to be up to date)

XAMPP is in **C:\xampp**

I run the XAMPP Control Panel as a **Adminstrator**

I installed Apache, MySQL, and FileZilla as a **Windows Service** from the XAMPP Control Panel

I pressed start for Apache and MySQL and the both are **running**.

The problem is: http://localhost/ is not available AND http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ is not available
Neither is **127.0.0.1**

> [Sat Aug 08 10:31:12.646044 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4780:tid 476]
>   Ans1909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an
>   ID which matches the server name

This the only warning I get. The rest is just normal notifications.

> [Sat Aug 08 10:31:13.646094 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4780:tid
>   476] Ans00455: Apache/2.4.12 (Winc32) OpenSSL/1.0.1m PHP/5.6.11
>   configured -- resuming normal operations [Sat Aug 08 10:31:13.646094
>   2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4780:tid 476] Ans00456: Apache Lounge
>   VC11 Server built: Mar 20 2018 12:12:41 [Sat Aug 08 10:31:13.646094
>   2018] [core:notice] [pid 4780:tid 476] Ans00094: Command line:
>   'C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache' [Sat Aug 08
>   10:31:15.083677 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4780:tid 476] Ans00418:
>   Parent: Created child process 4312
>
> 10:56:50 [main] Initializing Control Panel 10:56:50 [main] Windows
>   Version: Windows 8 64-bit 10:56:50 [main] XAMPP Version: 5.6.11
>   10:56:50 [main] Control Panel Version: 3.2.1 [ Compiled: May 7th 2018
>   ] 10:56:50 [main] Running with Administrator rights - good! 10:56:50
>   [main] XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\" 10:56:50 [main]
>   Checking for prerequisites 10:56:50 [main] All prerequisites found
>   10:56:50 [main] Initializing Modules 10:56:50 [mysql] XAMPP MySQL
>   Service is already running on port 3306 10:56:50 [main] Starting
>   Check-Timer 10:56:50 [main] Control Panel Ready 10:56:56 [Apache]
>   Attempting to start Apache service... 10:57:00 [Apache] Status change
>   detected: running 13:12:03 [main] Executing "services.msc"

Nothing else to report.

Any help is welcome. I'm a XAMPP virgin so please be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

It's a strange behavior, it's seems you have any strange thing in your vhost or on you hosts file, i can't remember where is exactly the hosts file in windows i suspect it can be in system32/drivers/etc ...
Check the file and if you find a line where your host localhost is pointing to antoher place just point it to 127.0.0.1
That should work

Comment: Thanks a lot my man. But I have decided to go the root of resetting my windows. Strange thing now is that I had windows 8.1 and now I have 8. Suspect that would change as soon as I am finished with all the updates. The important thing is that ampps is working brilliantly.